# Managing a larger JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, project-management

I was wondering, how are bigger JavaScript projects being maintained? I've been looking into AMD systems, such as RequireJS and BackboneJS.
However, I'd rather see my pack of JavaScript files being merged into one minified file using a build system or something. Looking at jQuery's Github repository, they seem to do something similar. 
So the question, are there build systems for JavaScript or any other approaches to merge multiple JS files to one?

Comment: You don't need anything specific to concatenate files. To minify the result, you have many solution, like Google's closure compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), it does this and much more!

With RequireJS you can use the [optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html)

Comment: Grunt certainly looks interesting. I'll have a closer look at it, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, I think Grunt is a promising project. My pleasure!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check [this URL](https://gist.github.com/desandro/4686136). A very nice discussion on Require.js featuring top JS technologists.